# Unable to activate SPI module on Raspberry Pi Zero W running on DietPi

Tags: raspbian, boot, spi, pi-zero-w

Ater setting up my Raspberry Pi Zero W with DietPi v150 I activated I2C module via the `dietpi-config` tool. However, I need to use SPI in addition and since there is no such option in the config tool I decided to go the manual way and edit `/boot/config.txt`. The original part of the file looks like this:

```
#-------spi-------------
dtparam=spi=off
```

Which I changed into:

```
#-------spi-------------
dtparam=spi=on
```

After saving the file and double-checking its contents again I rebooted the system by `sudo reboot` and reconnected via `ssh dietpi@192.168.0.1`.

I wanted to check whether the SPI module has been loaded correctly. So I typed `lsmod | grep 'spi*'` which printed nothing. So it seems that the module was not loaded and I tried `ls /dev/sp*` which raised `ls: cannot access /dev/sp*: No such file or directory`.
In order to get a clue about what was going on here I had a look into `/boot/config.txt` again:

```
#-------spi-------------
dtparam=spi=off
```

Which shows that SPI module should not be activated when booting the system. Since I edited the file, as described above, I think that somewhat replaces the `/boot/config.txt` with the default one during boot process.

I had another look around the Internet and found [this forum entry](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=130616) which is essentially the same procedure I used to enable SPI module and check its activation. Since they use DietPi as well, I am a bit confues about what is going on here.

Does anyone which process is overriding my edited `/boot/config.txt` during start-up or how I am able to enable the SPI module on DietPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that the `/boot/config.txt` is not accessed during system boot because of an additional version of this file on the DietPi-RamDisk.

The very first lines of the `/boot/config.txt` contain the following hint:

```
#Modifcations to /boot/* files, will not be saved when powered on.
#Please ensure you edit from the DietPi-RamDisk location /DietPi/*
```

So after accessing the correct version of the `config.txt` in `/DietPi/config.txt`, editing the desired line from

```
#-------spi-------------
dtparam=spi=off
```

to

```
#-------spi-------------
dtparam=spi=on
```

and the mandatory reboot the SPI module is loaded correctly as shown by:

```
dietpi@DietPi:~$ lsmod | grep spi
spidev                  7034  0 
spi_bcm2835             7424  0
```

*Note: A similar issue was discussed on the [DietPi forum](http://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=28)*